# How do i open a command-line program and send commands to them with java (android)

Tags: java, android, shell, sqlite, android-sqlite

How do I open a command-line program and send commands to them with java?
For example, I want to open SQLite3 and then send commands to it, and let it stay open.
I tried `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()`, but it only let me send one command and then exits SQLite3.

I'm trying to make an android app that will edit a sqlite database of another application (whatsapp)

Comment: Please explain more about your question.

Comment: you should develop your own console to achieve whatever u trying to do.. bcoz you can start external program using `Runtime` till the your code is in existence (in executable state). After Completion it will close the process. there should a child parent relationship between two processes to keep in control.

Comment: I'm trying to make an android app that will edit a sqlite database of another application (whatsapp)

Answer (score -1):

Try this one:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c start");
        System.out.println("ok");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Im making an android app